# how to move all files under one directory to home directory

Tags: files, directory, cp, mv

I have the script files script1.ksh ...script10.ksh in the directory star2

PATH : home/aaa/star2

I need to move all the files under star2 to the home directory (home/aaa)

NOTE : I do not want the folder star2 but I need all  files in this folder to come under home/aaa

current issue : home/aaa/star2/script1.ksh..rest of script files

what I needed : home/aaa/script1.ksh..rest of script files

command I used : cp -r /home/aaa/star2  ~

but I get error in console  saying

"cannot copy /home/aaa/star2 to /home/aaa/star2"

What do I need to do?

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro woud be helpful if u can share the answer .

Answer (score 1):

Command:

```
mv /home/aaa/star2/* ~/
rmdir /home/aaa/star2
```

Comment: * is used to recursively move ? wont it throw the same error cannot move /home/aaa/star2 to /home/aaa/star2

Comment: You should learn more about 'mv'.it would throw error if it had /home/aaa/star2/star2

Comment: there is only one  star2  file  and under  this file many script files are present .issue is how to remove this star2 files alone and not the script files inside it and bring these script files to home directory .

Comment: @star: Users on this site are encouraged to try to figure things out for themselves.  You've been given an answer; now you should read the documentation to figure out how it works.  If there's something in the documentation that you don't understand, *then* come back here and ask for more help.

Comment: @Fiximan : thank you so much  that works ...

Comment: @gman : the answer was edited just few min before you posted ur comments.